# A question regarding a problem in Folland

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = ae^{-nax}-be^{-nbx}$ where $0<a<b$.

Prove that
$$
\sum_1^\infty f_n \in L^1([0,\infty),m)\quad\text{and}\quad\int_0^\infty\sum_1^\infty f_n(x)\,dx=\log(b/a).
$$

This is the problem 27 of chapter 2 of Folland Real Analysis. Could anyone give me some helps about how to attack this problem? I can't think of any way...

Comment: Can you do $b=2,a=1$?

Comment: Was the list of problems preceded by something that says "Prove the following assertions"?  If so, why don't you tell us that?

Comment: This is routine: $\sum_{n \geq 1} f_n(x)$ is a sum of two geometric series. Just compute it and then integrate from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Because they are too trivial..

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ae^{-nax}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}be^{-nbx}=a(\frac{e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}})-b(\frac{e^{-bx}}{1-e^{-bx}})\in L^1([0, \infty),m)$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider part (2) first, then for every $m > 0$, $ae^{-anx},be^{-bnx}$ are bounded on $[0,m]$ and we have 
$$  \int_{0}^{m} ae^{-anx}  = \frac{1}{n}(1 - e^{-nam})
$$  for any $n$, by monotone convergence:
$$  \int_{0}^{\infty} f = \lim_{m} \frac{1}{n} (e^{-nbm} - e^{-nam}) = 0 
$$  and hence $\sum^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f = 0$.

Then consider part (1). For any $n$ and $x \geq \chi := \frac{\log (b/a)}{(b-a)n} > 0$, $ae^{-anx} \geq be^{-bnx}$ so 
$$  \int_{[0,\infty]} f \geq \int_{[\chi,\infty]} (ae^{-anx} - be^{-bnx}) = \frac{1}{n} (e^{-na\chi} - e^{-nb\chi}) = \frac{1}{n} C
$$  for a constant $C = \frac{b}{a}(e^{-\frac{a}{b-a}} - e^{-\frac{b}{b-a}}) > 0$. Because the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} C$ diverges, by comparison, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f$ diverges as well.

Then consider part (3). $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(x) = \frac{a e^{-ax}}{1 - e^{-ax}} - \frac{b e^{-bx}}{1 - e^{-bx}}$, and 
$$ \vert{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}}\vert = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}
$$because
$$ \frac{a e^{-ax}}{1 - e^{-ax}}  - \frac{b e^{-bx}}{1 - e^{-bx}} = \frac{e^{-bx}e^{-ax}}{(1-e^{-bx})(1-e^{-ax})}(ae^{bx} - be^{ax} - (a -b)) > 0 $$
by Taylor expansion of exponentials. Then 
$$ \int \vert{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}}\vert = \int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n} = \lim_{m\to \infty} \log(\frac{1-e^{-b/m}}{1 - e^{-a/m}}) = \log \frac{b}{a}
$$

Comment: Why $ae^{bx}-be^{ax}-(a-b) >0$?